# inconsistent gas limit estimation use existing address vs new addresses

Tags: solidity

I have been working on a smart contract that batch transfers ETHs to multiple addresses provided.
One thing i have noticed is that estimated gas limit for same addresses is `higher (almost double)` when there is no transaction so far against those addresses, reference [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9a894cfd5c61aee55fc2eede8b54bf9d76c26f8b2d65338ad45a07741ea81709). if addresses have some transactions already there then the `gas limit` decreases to half, reference [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x03099ba55a13cc0fa1a3a554ac31de4187c9d47f2a45244c2e3d301fed22ea67).

My question is:

- does it `gas limit` really depends on if an address has any transactions already ?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the G(newaccount) (~25k? gas not sure if changed) which is called to initialize new accounts. Below is a few ss from the pdf document I linked below for disperse.app which is popular for batch transfers.

Although it mainly covers ERC20 transfers, there's a section regarding native eth transfers as well and its relevant opcode/gas breakdowns which I believe is relevant to your question. Hope it helped!

[image: ERC20/token transfers]

[image: Native transfers]

A good reference for understanding gas optimizations and the opcode breakdown more detailed related to transfers is documented in the link below.
https://disperse.app/disperse.pdf